# Why is the address of the variable changing here?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am experimenting with pointers to get a better grip of it and I encountered this situation here:
I declared a variable var and two pointers. I was printing var's address to compare it with the two pointers but it kept changing between two values even though the statement was the same?

here is the first time when it gave the address of var to be `0061FF1C`:

the code I used :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main () {

   int  var;
   int  *ptr;
   int  **pptr;

   var = 3000;
   ptr = &var;
   pptr = &ptr;

   printf("Address of var = %p\n", &var );
   printf("Value available at ptr = %p\n", ptr ); // should be equal to address of Var
   printf("Address of ptr = %p\n", &ptr ); // should be equal to address of ptr
   printf("value available at pptr = %p\n", pptr); // should be equal to address of ptr
   printf("address of pptr = %p\n", &pptr ); // should be equal to address of pptr
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```txt
Address of var = 0061FF1C
Value available at ptr = 0061FF1C
Address of ptr = 0061FF18
value available at pptr = 0061FF18
address of pptr = 0061FF14
```

here is the second time when it gave the address of var to be `0061FF18`:
the code I used :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main () {

   int  var;
   int  *ptr;
   int  **pptr;

   var = 3000;
   ptr = &var;
   pptr = &ptr;

   printf("Address of var = %p\n", &var );
   printf("Value available at ptr = %p\n", ptr ); // should be equal to address of Var
   printf("value available at pptr = %p\n", pptr); // should be equal to address of ptr

   return 0;
}
```

the output:

```txt
Address of var = 0061FF18
Value available at ptr = 0061FF18
value available at pptr = 0061FF14
```

I was expecting the values of var to be the same each time
why did it change?

Comment: As I see it, pptr's value is the address of ptr, ptr's value is the address of var, var's address is the address of var. Two of these are expected to be the same.

Comment: In each output, you get same addresses twice. Which addresses do you expect to be the same? All addresses? Why? How would output for `// should be equal to address of ptr` be same as for `// should be equal to address of pptr` ? Two variables don't share same address.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I understand and I pointed that out in the comments but here the address of var changes the second time and I don't understand why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @pmg: Address space layout randomization does not account for a change of four bytes. It works in units of virtual memory pages.

Comment: @AKX: The question is not why `&val` abd `ptr` are the same in one run. It is why `&val` is 0061FF1C in one program and 0061FF18 in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the program that does not print `&pptr`, that object does not need to have an address, so the compiler is able to optimize the program by not actually storing it in memory. The program can hold the value of `pptr` in a processor register and/or create it “on the fly” as needed. Since no memory is allocated for it, this changes where other objects, like `var`, are located.

Compilers may use complicated algorithms to assign memory to objects. However, in this limited question, we can consider a simplistic view. Essentially, the compiler prepares information about the objects it needs to store on the stack and then assigns locations in the stack frame of `main` for those objects, with the result that the first object it assigns a location for will end up at address 0061FF14<sub>16</sub>, the next at 0061FF18<sub>16</sub>, and the next at 0061FF1C<sub>16</sub>. (There are other things in the stack frame, which is why the first object we see in this case starts at 0061FF14<sub>16</sub> rather than, say, 0061FF10<sub>16</sub>.)

In the first version of your program, the program prints the addresses of `var`, `ptr`, and `pptr`. So those objects must have addresses. For whatever reason, the compiler handles them in the order `pptr`, `ptr`, and `var`, giving them the addresses 0061FF14<sub>16</sub>, 0061FF18<sub>16</sub>, and 0061FF1C<sub>16</sub>, respectively.

In the second version of your program, the program prints the addresses of `var` and of `ptr` (the latter by assigning `&ptr` to `pptr` and then printing `pptr`). It never uses the address of `pptr`, so `pptr` does not need to have an actual address; the compiler is able to make the program work without ever putting `pptr` in memory. So, for this program, the compiler allocates memory for `var` and `ptr`, and they end up at address 0061FF14<sub>16</sub> and 0061FF18<sub>16</sub>. So the address of `ptr` differs by four bytes from the first version of the program.